# bsearch() in C giving segmentation fault in new gcc version 7.4.0

Tags: c, bsearch

I have an old program in C which uses `bsearch()` function with `strcmp()` from the C library. In old gcc version4.4.7, it is running properly. But in latest Ubuntu 18.04 with gcc version7.4.0, it is giving segmentation fault. Code is given below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <search.h>

#define MAX_CHR_IN_STR 50 
#define MAX_CHR_IN_DEMO_STR 86
#define GENDER 4
#define NUMBER 4
#define PERSON 4
#define TOTAL_ENTRY 2
#define MEDIUM 50

struct mytam_gnpstr {
    char mytam[MAX_CHR_IN_STR];
    char mytam_lbl[MAX_CHR_IN_STR];
    char gnp_str[MAX_CHR_IN_DEMO_STR];
    char gen_pos[GENDER]; 
    char num_pos[NUMBER]; 
    char per_pos[PERSON]; 
};

struct mytam_gnpstr mytam_gnpstr_array[TOTAL_ENTRY] = {
    "0", "0", "0[-,s,m]", "0", "s", "m",
    "0_0_kara", "0_0_kara", "02[-,-,-]kara_0[-,-,-]", "0", "0", "0",
};

int main(void) {
    char *rtamexample;
    char TAM[MEDIUM] = "wA";
    fprintf(stderr, "TAM :::::::: %s\n", TAM);
    fprintf(stderr, "mytam_gnpstr_array[0].mytam :::::::: %s\n",
            mytam_gnpstr_array[0].mytam);
    fprintf(stderr, "TOTAL_ENTRY :::::::: %d\n", TOTAL_ENTRY);
    fprintf(stderr, "sizeof(mytam_gnpstr_array[0]) :::::::: %zu\n",
            sizeof(mytam_gnpstr_array[0]));

    rtamexample = (char *)bsearch(TAM, mytam_gnpstr_array[0].mytam, TOTAL_ENTRY,
                                  (sizeof(mytam_gnpstr_array[0])), strcmp);
    fprintf(stderr, "bsearch :::::::: %s\n", rtamexample);
}
```

It is giving `bsearch()` output `"wA"` in old gcc version-4.7.7
but It is giving segmentation fault in gcc7.4.0.
Any help solving this is appreciated.

Comment: Try adding `#include <stdlib.h>`

Comment: Its compiling properly but with two warnings on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Correct those warnings (without using a cast) and see what you get.

Comment: `main(argc, argv)int argc; char *argv[]` ... from the way back machine!!

Comment: What warnings? You don't mention them in your question.

Comment: Don't use the K&R notation for functions — you should never write `main(argc, argv) int argc; char **argv; { … }` in new code.  AFAIAC, it's uncompilable — I use compiler options to explicitly outlaw that.  You have to have an extraordinarily good reason to use that notation these days.  And that's been true for the whole of this millennium.  It's doubly true when you don't use either `argc` or `argv` in the function.  It should be `int main(void) { … }`.

Comment: @WilliamPursell : Yes it is the code written in late 90's

Comment: `strcmp` is not a valid comparison function to pass to `bsearch`. It requires `int (*)(const void *, const void *)` not `int (*)(const char *, const char *)`. This probably isn't the cause of the crash, but it is a constraint violation as written and UB if you add a cast to try to "make the warning go away". You need a wrapper function around `strcmp`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler : thanks I corrected the main in question.

Comment: Your `bsearch` call makes no sense. Are you trying to find a string `TAM` in a string `mytam_gnpstr_array[0].mytam`? `mytam_gnpstr_array[0].mytam` is an array of `MAX_CHR_IN_STR` characters, not `TOTAL_ENTRY`. And if you meant to compare the structure, then `strcmp` will not compare `struct mytam_gnpstr*` with `char*`. The data passed to `bsearch` need to be sorted.

Comment: The code seems to be playing fast and loose with types.  You've got an array of a structure type.  You're trying to pretend that it is an array of fixed size strings.  The data doesn't contain an entry with `"wA"` in it, so the `bsearch()` should return a null pointer, which you then try to print.  That might trigger a segmentation fault, though depressingly often modern libraries try to protect the careless programmer from their malfeasance by printing `(null)` or something similar when a null pointer is passed for formatting with `%s`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I know it is kind of null pointer exception of java. But in old gcc in same scenario the code is running fine with output "wA". I will have to replicate the same in new gcc. As it is typical research project I can not skip even an exception output it was giving in old gcc.

Comment: What answer were you getting? There's no entry in the array even containing `wA` as part of the data, so it is not clear how you could get anything other than a NULL pointer back.  IMNSHO, the old code is broken and needs a modestly major rewrite to work — with any version of GCC.  I'm open to persuasion otherwise, but the code shown has many flaws, and there is no respectable result other than a NULL pointer available as the return value from `bsearch()`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: In old OS same core was returning "wA"

Comment: You saiy: "In the old OS, same code was returning `'wA"`" — to me, that's a positive indication that the code is broken.  How can the search find `wA` in the array when it doesn't exist in the data?'

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: that was shocking to me too when I was trying to re-engineer the tool. That an element is absent but its returning "wA" in gcc 4.7.0. I still have same OS in a server and running on it giving "wA".

Comment: It's impossible to reliably reproduce the same result for undefined behaviour.  The old code is broken.  It cannot reliably be made to run the same with the new compiler because the behaviour expected is undefined.

Comment: Was the old system 32-bit or 64-bit?  What was the platform for the old system — o/s and version?  Is it reasonable to assume that the new Ubuntu 18.04 LTS system is 64-bit?  I've not tried to find a 32-bit version, but…

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: yes both are 64 bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The old code is broken.  It is apparently producing an answer out of thin air; the data value `wA` does not appear anywhere in the array being searched, so any answer other than a NULL pointer is bogus.  If the code shown, when compiled on the old system, produces `wA` as an answer, the code is IMNSHO self-evidently broken.

Here is code which conforms to what's needed.  It includes `<stdlib.h>` since that is where `bsearch()` is declared.  It does not include `<search.h>` since that does not declare anything the code uses.  Ditto for `<ctype.h>`.  It tells `bsearch()` about the array of structures it is searching, rather than passing a pointer to the start of the first member of the first element of the array.  The comparator function passed in the code in the question is `strcmp()`; its prototype does not match the function pointer type expected by `bsearch()`, so you officially get undefined behaviour there.  The comparator function in this code works correctly, and expects to be given a pair of pointers to the structure type, cast to `const void *` by `bsearch()`.  The first pointer will be the key being searched for; the second will be a row from the array being searched.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_CHR_IN_STR 50
#define MAX_CHR_IN_DEMO_STR 86
#define GENDER 4
#define NUMBER 4
#define PERSON 4
#define MEDIUM 50

struct mytam_gnpstr
{
    char mytam[MAX_CHR_IN_STR];
    char mytam_lbl[MAX_CHR_IN_STR];
    char gnp_str[MAX_CHR_IN_DEMO_STR];
    char gen_pos[GENDER];
    char num_pos[NUMBER];
    char per_pos[PERSON];
};

struct mytam_gnpstr mytam_gnpstr_array[] =
{
    { "0", "0", "0[-,s,m]", "0", "s", "m", },
    { "0_0_kara", "0_0_kara", "02[-,-,-]kara_0[-,-,-]", "0", "0", "0", },
    { "wA", "Match", "Match", "0", "123", "ZZZ" },
    { "zB", "Unmatch", "Unmatch", "0", "123", "ZZZ" },
};

enum { TOTAL_ENTRY = sizeof(mytam_gnpstr_array) / sizeof(mytam_gnpstr_array[0]) };

static int comparator(const void *v1, const void *v2)
{
    const struct mytam_gnpstr *p1 = v1;
    const struct mytam_gnpstr *p2 = v2;
    return strcmp(p1->mytam, p2->mytam);
}

int main(void)
{
    struct mytam_gnpstr key = { .mytam = "wA" };

    fprintf(stderr, "TAM :::::::: %s\n", key.mytam);
    fprintf(stderr, "mytam_gnpstr_array[0].mytam :::::::: %s\n", mytam_gnpstr_array[0].mytam);
    fprintf(stderr, "TOTAL_ENTRY :::::::: %d\n", TOTAL_ENTRY);
    fprintf(stderr, "sizeof(mytam_gnpstr_array[0]) :::::::: %zu\n", sizeof(mytam_gnpstr_array[0]));

    struct mytam_gnpstr *res = bsearch(&key, mytam_gnpstr_array, TOTAL_ENTRY,
                                    sizeof(mytam_gnpstr_array[0]), comparator);

    if (res == 0)
        fprintf(stderr, "Did not find entry matching\n");
    else
        fprintf(stderr, "bsearch :::::::: %s ('%s', '%s')\n",
                res->mytam, res->mytam_lbl, res->gnp_str);

    return 0;
}
```

When compiled as shown, it produces the output:

```
TAM :::::::: wA
mytam_gnpstr_array[0].mytam :::::::: 0
TOTAL_ENTRY :::::::: 4
sizeof(mytam_gnpstr_array[0]) :::::::: 198
bsearch :::::::: wA ('Match', 'Match')
```

When the entry with `wA` is commented out, it produces the output:

```
TAM :::::::: wA
mytam_gnpstr_array[0].mytam :::::::: 0
TOTAL_ENTRY :::::::: 3
sizeof(mytam_gnpstr_array[0]) :::::::: 198
Did not find entry matching
```

This behaviour is correct.

With the data in the question (two lines, nary a `wA` anywhere in the array), you will never get anything other than NULL back from a valid invocation of `bsearch()`.  Expecting anything else is an exercise in futility.

JFTR: compiled on macOS Mojave 10.14.6 (don't ask why it isn't Catalina) with GCC 9.2.0 and Xcode 11.3.1.  I'd expect the same results on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, or indeed any system where C99 is available.  Indeed, it should work the same with C90, too.

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes \
>     bs47.c -o bs47
$
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I have a query that In the mentioned scenario would the bsearch would search in the first field of the array of structures: mytam or in complete element?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems in the code:

- you forgot to include `<stdlib.h>`, hence `bsearch` is not declared and the prototype inferred by the compiler from the call is incorrect: `TOTAL_ENTRY` has type `int`, not `size_t`, which has a different representation on 64-bit systems.
- The arguments you pass to `bsearch()` are inconsistent, you should pass pointers to `mytam_gnpstr` structures and an appropriate comparison function that calls `strcmp()`.
- the comparison function `strcmp()` does not have the proper prototype anyway, it gets pointers to `char` by coincidence.
- the return value from `bsearch()` should be cast as `(struct mytam_gnpstr *)` and tested for `NULL`.

Comment: It is still giving warning and null output.